# How to run the function without showing the push message when it is sent?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I have a problem to solve with a push message. If I send a push message to **`Firebase`**,I will receive it well and I will see the message well.

And when I click on the push message, the `userNotificationCenter` function in the `AppDelegate` file is executed and the list of actions in the function is executed.

Can I execute a function without receiving a specific message and displaying a message?

### Where I'm currently receiving and processing push messages.

```swift
    @available(iOS 10, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let data = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

        guard
            let push = data[AnyHashable("push")] as? String,
            let getdata = data[AnyHashable("getdata")] as? String,
            let pushdata = data[AnyHashable("pushdata")] as? String
            else {
                print("it's not good data")
                return
        }
        print(push)
        print(getdata)
        print(pushdata)
}

   @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
    {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
```

My purpose is to execute the function without showing the push message to the user when sending a specific message `(Ex: push = "noShowPush")` from the Firebase.

### EDit

I was tried `"content_available": true`
but get log  `6.10.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002019] FIRMessaging received data-message, but FIRMessagingDelegate's-messaging:didReceiveMessage: not implemented`

```swift
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        //create the notificationCenter
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        //Register App For Push Notification
        //        self.registerAppForPushNotificaition()
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        let inviteCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "Notification", actions: [], intentIdentifiers: [], options: UNNotificationCategoryOptions.customDismissAction)
        let categories = NSSet(objects: inviteCategory)

        center.delegate = self
        center.setNotificationCategories(categories as! Set<UNNotificationCategory>)
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        })
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        self.updateAppViewUI()
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
 }
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics

         Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(userInfo) {
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)
            return
        }
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
```

I have it already `Messaging.messaging().delegate = self`.

The logs in the `Firebase` have warned you to set `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` to `No`, so I added to the `Info.list`.
[image]

and `Firebase` log changed  `[Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add '[FIRApp configure];' ('FirebaseApp.configure()' in Swift) to your application initialization. Read more:`

Are the things I'm revising are going right?

How can I this solution?

Comment: What you are actually trying to achieve? Your question seems to be unclear.

Comment: Is my question hard to understand? My purpose is to execute the function without showing the push message to the user when sending a specific message (Ex: push = "noShowPush") from the Firebase.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  I think you can solve the problem in firebase. Would you help me with my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. Here's the order in which I've worked out:

1. Write when you send a push `"content_available": true"`. And don't
   include the `title` and `body`.
2. And when I got these error logs,  `6.10.0 -
   [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002019] FIRMessaging received
   data-message, but
   FIRMessagingDelegate's-messaging:didReceiveMessage: not implemented`
3. The logs in the Firebase have warned you to set
   `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` to No, so I added to the
   `Info.list`.

   [image: ㅎㅎ]
4. and changed the order of execution of the function.

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

       FirebaseApp.configure() // Let it run first.
       Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
       self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
       ...
   ```
5. And I installed `'Firebase/Analytics'` on the pod.
   `pod 'Firebase/Analytics'`
6. and inherited the `MessagingDelegate` and implemented the
   `Messaging` function.

   ```
   func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
       print("fcmToken \(fcmToken)")
   }

   func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
       Log.Info("remort \(remoteMessage.appData)")
       let userInfo = remoteMessage.appData
   }
   ```

This configuration allows you to receive push message data into the `messaging` function when a push message is sent. This is a push message with a '`contentAvailable`' value of `True` and no `title` and `body`.